# How to find geodesics in a Randers spaces?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geodesics, finsler-geometry

Consider a Randers space $(M,F)$ that is the solution of the zermelo's navigation problem associated to a wind $W$ which is homothety; $\mathcal{L}_Wh=\sigma h$, $\delta$ constant, on a Riemannian space $(M,h)$. Then the Randers geodesics can be found using Theorem 2 of [Robles](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0501358.pdf).

Now I am wondering if there is any way with which one can find the Randers geodesics of the Randers space ($\mathbb{R}^3,F$) which comes from putting the wind $W=(b+a\sin kx,0,0)$ on the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$. By using the equation of the geodesics it sounds quite difficult.

P.S.: here $a, b$ and $k$ are some constant.

Comment: What main difficulty are you encountering?

Comment: It demands lot of calculations and one has to deal with a differential equation which is not so easy to be solved.

Comment: If it‘s just a lot of work, you could try a CAS. What is the differential equation you are struggling with?

Comment: @S.Surace What is CAS?
I am dealing with an Abel equation of the first kind!

Comment: I‘m referring to a computer algebra system, e.g. Mathematica.